# Global Anti-Xss method for all input-type: text, password, email objects

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, xss

Is there any way to apply global anti-xss function to all 'Old' and 'New' input boxes? I know that it is more recommended to apply this function on each input objects but the requirement said it should be global.

Here is the sample code that I saw:

```
$rootScope.globalTextValidation = function () {                        

    angular.forEach(angular.element('input'), function (f) {
        var txt = angular.element('#' + f.id).val();
        var result1 = txt.indexOf("<") > -1;
        var result2 = txt.indexOf(">") > -1;                

        if (result1 || result2) {
            txt = txt.replace('<', '&lt;');
            txt = txt.replace('>', '&gt;');
            angular.element('#' + f.id).val(txt);
        }
    });

};

USAGE:

<input id="searchQuickAdd" type="text" placeholder="Enter product code..." ng-model="quickProductNum"  name="code" ng-change="globalTextValidation()" ng-paste="globalTextValidation()"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't this give a false sense of security, since the user can simply edit this snippet for an XSS attack?

Comment: @Roberrrt I agree. So what do you suggest? :)

Comment: I'd suggest server side validation for serious breaches, and client side validation to give feedback so the page doesn't reload, think about 'passwords do not match' or 'login isn't long enough' (which can be done with javascript) and illegal tokens should be escaped on the server.

Comment: @Roberrrt server side validation is already done but they also want to apply it on the client side. And they want it to be implemented 'globally'. At least based on what you have said I got something that I could tell them.

Comment: You're using jQuery right? I'm not really familliar with Angular, but I can write some example pseudocode to give you a general idea what i'm talking about, also ++ for the SS validation.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean with 'old' and 'new' ? Are you inserting them dynamically?